# Comparison between secant and derivative in a convex function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Imagine that we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is convex, that is $f''>0$. We also know that $f'''<0$, that is its first derivative function is concave. Now, we can define its secant to be
\begin{equation}
R\left(x_1,x_2\right)\equiv\frac{f\left(x_2\right)-f\left(x_1\right)}{x_2-x_1}\text{ for }x_2>x_1
\end{equation}
which is a symmetric function. Now let's fix $x_2$ and let $x_1$ vary. Now, here are the questions

> Is $R\left(x_1,x_2\right)$ is concave as well in $x_1$ (that is $\partial_1^2 R\left(x_1,x_2\right)<0$ ) ?

and

> Is $\partial_1 R\left(x_1,x_2\right)>f''(x_1)$ ?

Comment: Do you know the Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! Indeed that proves easily the first question (simply take derivatives on both sides of mean value theorem statement) but what about the second?

Comment: hi again! do you have any hint for the second part? :-)